# Can gravity distort space to form new eigenvectors?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature

What I'm asking is, whether gravity can distort space SO STRONGLY that it creates a totally new direction that didn't exist in the absence of that gravity?

To imagine my question, propose that space without gravity is 2-dimensional (left-right and forward-back).

Can the existence of mass/gravity field creates a new directional eigenvector (up-down, the direction towards the center of the gravity field). I am envisioning that this space would then be 3d due to the distortion.

Correspondingly in our 3D universe, can this happen? If there is a strong gravitational distortion nearby, can it distort space into what appears to be a fourth cardinal direction?

Comment: Note that describing curvature of a surface in general relativity (and more generally in differential geometry) doesn't require that the surface be embedded in a higher dimensional space. See [Gauss' Theorema Egregium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is a straight "no". General Relativity takes as a premise that spacetime can be accurately treated as a 4-dimensional region, and the whole structure of the theory maintains this and never changes this. All the distortion related to gravity (or the distortion that we call gravity) is a kind of stretching of some parts of this spacetime relative to other parts, somewhat as you can distort fabric by pulling on it.

General Relativity is not itself the last word on the nature of spacetime, but I believe the question was intended to address that model and what it does and does not imply.